# jQuery Replace value in select depending on other select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array:

```
var LWTable = [];
LWTable.push([6,200,200,220]);
LWTable.push([8,220,220,240]);
LWTable.push([10,240,240,260]);
LWTable.push([12,260,260,290]);
LWTable.push([15,290,310,340]);
LWTable.push([18,330,360,400]);
LWTable.push([21,385,420,460]);
```

And the following html:

```
<select name="plength" id="plength">
  <option value="6" selected>6 in.</option>
  <option value="8">8 in.</option>
  <option value="10">10 in.</option>
  <option value="12">12 in.</option>
  <option value="15">15 in.</option>
  <option value="18">18 in.</option>
  <option value="21">21 in.</option>
</select>
<select name="pwidth" id="pwidth">
  <option value="Width1" selected>Width 1 (xw1x)</option>
  <option value="Width2">Width 2 (xw2x)</option>
  <option value="Width3">Width 3 (xw3x)</option>
</select>
```

What I want is, that when I select value 8 for plength, that in the pwidth select box, the xw1x, xw2x and xw3x strings are replaced by the values from the MinLoadTable, so that in this example it would show 220, 220 and 240.
When I pick 21, it will automatically replace that text with 385,420,460.

Is this possible and if so how? I tried to look up some examples, but didn't get anywhere...
Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use a multi-dimensional array for the data? It seems as though an object keyed by the values of `plength` would be much, much simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, not necessarily... at least not in this format.

Comment: In which case I've added an answer for you below.

Comment: .. the only problem that I have now (my bad) is that I used "width 1, width 2", etc, but they will have other values.. so I can't simply use a number in there...

Comment: Where do the other values come from? If they're part of the dataset yoy could just concatenate them as i am in the example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nevermind.. What I meant was that I don't necessarily have Width1, width2, width3, but also widtha, widthabc, etc. But I got it figured out. Thanks! (Plus the values also don't have the numbers in it, like you gave in your solution, but again.. I worked around that. Your solution helped me out nonetheless!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its possible to change the data structure in the JS code to an object you can make this very striaghtforward. Firstly you can create the `plength` select options on load from the keys of the object. Then on change of `plength` you can use the selected value to find the key in the object and populate the options of `pwidth`. Try this:

```js
var LWTable = {
  '6': [200, 200, 220],
  '8': [220, 220, 240],
  '10': [240, 240, 260],
  '12': [260, 260, 290],
  '15': [290, 310, 340],
  '18': [330, 360, 400],
  '21': [385, 420, 460],
}

var plengthOptions = '';
Object.keys(LWTable).forEach(function(key) {
  plengthOptions += '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' in.</option>';
});

$('#plength').append(plengthOptions).change(function() {
  var pwidthOptions = '';
  LWTable[this.value].forEach(function(width, i) {
    pwidthOptions += '<option value="Width' + (i + 1) + '">Width' + (i + 1) + ' (' + width + ')</option>';
  });
  $('#pwidth').html(pwidthOptions);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="plength" id="plength"></select>
<select name="pwidth" id="pwidth"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, this answer was awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```js
$(function(){

    var LWTable = [];
    LWTable.push([6,200,200,220]);
    LWTable.push([8,220,220,240]);
    LWTable.push([10,240,240,260]);
    LWTable.push([12,260,260,290]);
    LWTable.push([15,290,310,340]);
    LWTable.push([18,330,360,400]);
    LWTable.push([21,385,420,460]);
  
    $("#plength").change(function(){
        var ele = $(this)
        var length = ele.val();
        var widths = LWTable.find(function(item){
            return item[0] == length;
        });
        if(widths){
            var $pWidth = $("#pwidth");
            $pWidth.empty();
            $.each(widths.slice(1), function(key,value) {
                var txt = 'Width'+(key+1)+' ('+value+')';
                $pWidth.append($("<option></option>")
                       .attr("value", value)
                       .text(txt));
            });
        }
    });
  
   $("#plength").trigger("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="plength" id="plength">
  <option value="6" selected>6 in.</option>
  <option value="8">8 in.</option>
  <option value="10">10 in.</option>
  <option value="12">12 in.</option>
  <option value="15">15 in.</option>
  <option value="18">18 in.</option>
  <option value="21">21 in.</option>
</select>
<select name="pwidth" id="pwidth">
  <option value="Width1" selected>Width 1 (xw1x)</option>
  <option value="Width2">Width 2 (xw2x)</option>
  <option value="Width3">Width 3 (xw3x)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Looks great, but is there a way to get it also to replace upon load? (since the initial value hasn't been replaced)

Comment: Is there an easy way to update your code so instead of using 'Width'+(key+1)+' ('+value+')' it will use whatever is there? (I know, my bad, but I simplified my example so it was incrementing, while it actually isn't...)

Comment: @Malachi ofcourse this can be done and I think that is fairly easy ! Did you try it? Did you find any obstacle?