# jQuery Remember value of dynamically generated selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have the following code:

```
var LWTable = {
  '6': [200, 200, 220],
  '8': [220, 220, 240],
  '10': [240, 240, 260],
  '12': [260, 260, 290],
  '15': [290, 310, 340],
  '18': [330, 360, 400],
  '21': [385, 420, 460],
}

var plengthOptions = '';
Object.keys(LWTable).forEach(function(key) {
  plengthOptions += '<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' in.</option>';
});

$('#plength').append(plengthOptions).change(function() {
  var pwidthOptions = '';
  LWTable[this.value].forEach(function(width, i) {
    pwidthOptions += '<option value="Width' + (i + 1) + '">Width' + (i + 1) + ' (' + width + ')</option>';
  });
  $('#pwidth').html(pwidthOptions);
}).change();

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="plength" id="plength"></select>
<select name="pwidth" id="pwidth"></select>
```

The above works great (see also [jQuery Replace value in select depending on other select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510533/jquery-replace-value-in-select-depending-on-other-select-box)) and is in $( document ).ready(function() 
However.. whenever I reload the page, whatever I selected is not there anymore.. it resets to the default, which is not what I want. How can I have it "remember" the value? I assume I need to use localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem, however, I have no clue how. I tried a few things, resulting in the whole thing not working anymore..

How/where do I do the getItem (picking up the correct value) and where do I do the setItem, so it sets it upon value change?

Comment: On select change set value to localStorage, on page load read value and set selection in selectbox.

Comment: @dfsq Where do I set it? Inside the change(function) part? To me it looks like everything takes places at the "same time" (writing the plengthOptions and pwidthOptions I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the below in all my projects so all I have to do is add `data-local-key="some-key"` to any element that I want to "remember" its value. (dont forget to change `some-key` to something meaningful for each element and be distinctive so they dont overlap down the road.

#### [See working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/24/)

```js
  $(document).on('blur','[data-local-key]',function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    if (window.localStorage) {
      window.localStorage.setItem($this.data('local-key'), $this.val());
    }
  });
  $('[data-local-key]').each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.val(window.localStorage.getItem($this.data('local-key')));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" data-local-key="some-key" id="">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Note that I havent used it with checkboxes, not sure that would work, but I rarely use checkboxes so its not an issue.

Comment: That was awesome... one issue though: I have a (text) field that changes due to the value of one of those select boxes. The select box now keeps the value, but the text field does not. Any idea how I can keep it's value? Before I used the data-local-key for the text field, it would use the default value of the checkbox (before the data-local-key changes it to what was in localStorage)...

Comment: @Malachi it sounds like you just need to make sure that the `$('[data-local-key]').each(....` function runs *before* your code that sets the text input value that way when your code runs, the  `data-local-key` value has already been set and your input will be set correctly. Just put this code above your code instead of at the end

Comment: My bad.. Just found out that it didn't work.... BECAUSE I didn't go to the field itself. Your code uses a 'blur' for the specific text field. If I click on the field and then go to another.. then it stores the value. Otherwise it won't...

Comment: I just made a workaround with   window.localStorage.setItem($('#fieldid').data('local-key'), $('#fieldid').val()); right after your window.localStorage line, so that it'll storage that field as well, no matter what...

Answer (score -1):

You would call `getItem()` when you're building your options, and `setItem()` in a `change` event on the select to store the new value.

Your code is doing a bit much for me to edit it directly, but here is a basic sample.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const lastValue = localStorage.getValue('lastValue');
    const values = [1,2,3,4,5];

    const $select = $('<select>');
    values.forEach(value => $select.append(`
        <option value="${value}">${value}</option>
    `);
    $select.val(lastValue);

    $select.change(() => { 
        localStorage.setValue('lastValue', $select.val());
    });
});
```

In your particular case, you'll have two layers of this it looks like, one for your `#plength` and one for `#pwidth`, but the idea is still the same: set the value of your `select` to `localStorage.getItem('key')` and on change call `localStorage.setItem('key', $yourSelect.val())` to store the value.

If you need more help, take a stab at getting it to work and start a new question with your updated code.

Comment: Anyone care to comment why the downvote? My answer solves the problem. I'm going to let them attempt to at least take a stab at implementing it themselves instead of writing their whole application.

Comment: You're using ES6 notation when there is no reason to believe the OP will understand it given their code doesnt use it.